# Error using WWW::YouTube::Download in perl

Tags: perl, youtube, perl-module

I installed [WWW::YouTube::Download](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::YouTube::Download) module for downloading youtube videos and implemented it using the code below

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::YouTube::Download;

my $video_id="http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=TLNsL47LmBlyoKYinLLPSOkS7jlnl2V6u_&v=hzrGAZnMOMQ";
my $client = WWW::YouTube::Download->new;
$client->download($video_id);

my $video_url = $client->get_video_url($video_id);
my $title     = $client->get_title($video_id);     # maybe encoded utf8 string.
my $fmt       = $client->get_fmt($video_id);       # maybe highest quality.
my $suffix    = $client->get_suffix($video_id);    # maybe highest quality file suffix
```

The Following error is displayed

garbage after JSON object, at character offset 25151 (before ";(function() {var en...") at  C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/www/YouTube/Download.pm at line 226

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

The `$video_id` argument to `download` should just be `hzrGAZnMOMQ`, not the complete video URI.

Comment: I tried only the above id. It is displaying the same error.

Comment: @navin you're right, I get the same error. YouTube may have changed their API or it may be a bug in the module.